# Pandas data frame spread function or similar?

Tags: python, pandas

Here's a pandas df:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'First' : ['John', 'Jane', 'Mary'], 
                      'Last' : ['Smith', 'Doe', 'Johnson'], 
                      'Group' : ['A', 'B', 'A'], 
                      'Measure' : [2, 11, 1]})

df
Out[38]: 
  First     Last Group  Measure
0  John    Smith     A        2
1  Jane      Doe     B       11
2  Mary  Johnson     A        1
```

I would like to "spread" the Group variable with the values in Measure.

```
df_desired
Out[39]: 
  First     Last  A   B
0  John    Smith  2   0
1  Jane      Doe  0  11
2  Mary  Johnson  1   0
```

Each level within `Group` variable becomes its own column populated with the values contained in column `Measure`. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Using `pivot_table`

```
df.pivot_table(index=['First','Last'],columns='Group',values='Measure',fill_value=0)
Out[247]: 
Group          A   B
First Last          
Jane  Doe      0  11
John  Smith    2   0
Mary  Johnson  1   0
```

Comment: Thanks, but the output here has both First and Last combined into one variable as opposed to being their own separate columns. Is there a way to modify so that the columns in index remain as stand alone columns?

Comment: @DougFir adding .reset_index() at the end

Answer (score 2):

If your order doesn't matter, you can do something along these lines:

```
df.set_index(['First','Last', 'Group']).unstack('Group').fillna(0).reset_index()

      First     Last Measure      
Group                      A     B
0      Jane      Doe     0.0  11.0
1      John    Smith     2.0   0.0
2      Mary  Johnson     1.0   0.0
```

Comment: Thanks, this gets closer to what my desired output is. I personally find it less readable than what wen wrote above using pivot_table().

Comment: So do I, as a matter of fact! Wen's should be accepted IMO